# Swapping elements in array doesn't work when using function pointer

Tags: c++

So i want to use AscendingSort() and DecendingSort() as an argument but it seems like after return the value the swap part just get skipped, hope someone explain to me, thanks!.

```
        bool AscendingSort(int a, int b)
        {
            return a > b;
        }
        bool DecendingSort(int a, int b)
        {
            return a < b;
        }
    
        void SortArray(int* a, int size, bool(*func)(int, int))
        {
            int saveElement;
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                for (int y = x + 1; y < size; y++)
                {
                    if (func(a[x], a[y]))
                    {
                        saveElement = a[x];
                        a[x] == a[y];           //Those 2 lines getting skipped.
                        a[y] == saveElement;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    void main()
    {
        int a[1000];
    
        int arrSize;
    
        SortArray(a, arrSize, AscendingSort);
    
    };
```

Comment: Is this really the code you are running?  Because you neither initialized `a` nor `arrSize`, causing the function call to be full of *undefined behavior*

Comment: whats wrong with the code? What do you mean with "//Those 2 lines getting skipped." ? How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: Instead of hand coding swap use `std::swap` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap available in the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

You probably meant to use `=` operator instead of `==`.

Comment: Lol, sorry, that was a dumbest mistake